# Intermediate Value Theorem on continuous function with range.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ with $f(1)=f(0)=0$ and  $f(\frac{1}{2})$ =1 .Show that

(1)  there exist some a $\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ such that $f(a)=a$

while this just can be proved by using the intermediate value theorem and I have solved it. But the second part made me confuse,

(2)  for any real number $\lambda$ , there exist some point $\varepsilon \in (0,a)$ such that $f'(\varepsilon)-1=\lambda(f(\varepsilon)-\varepsilon))$

For the second part, why there's a $f'(\varepsilon)$ there? and how I can approach the proof of second part?

Comment: For any real number $\lambda$? Like this it can't be true. Take $f(x)= -4 x^2 + 4x$ and a really big $\lambda$.

Comment: Maybe you can post the exact statement or where you have it from? Maybe there is a typo or something similar.

Comment: I double-check the question and the question is exactly the same with what I post. So maybe the question itself has a problem?

Comment: I think it is false, yes. Maybe you can ask your instructor or a peer for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Can I use Mean Value Theorem (MVT) to prove part(2)??

$f'(\varepsilon)=\frac{f(\varepsilon)-f(0)}{\varepsilon-0}$  such that we have:

$f'(\varepsilon)=\frac{f(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}$

Each side minus one at the same time

$f'(\varepsilon)-1=\frac{f(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}-1$

then we have what we want:

$f'(\varepsilon)-1=\lambda(f(\varepsilon)-\varepsilon)$

Comment: That's not the mean value theorem, is it? Also do you just substitute one $\varepsilon$ for an arbitrary (!) $\lambda$ in the last step?

Comment: yep you are correct, I should try another approach

Comment: I think you should really check if it is the right statement you want to prove. Because I think the way it is stated it is not correct.